# Undefined reference using namespace C++

Tags: c++, namespaces, undefined-reference

When I want to run the code the compiler says `undefined reference to math::calc`

I read questions and answers about this problem at StackOverflow and it do not help me solve my problem.

Comp.h

```cpp
#include <utility>
namespace math {
    typedef std::pair<double,double> Comp;
    double getFirst(Comp a);
    ...
}
```

Comp.cpp

```cpp
#include "comp.h"
namespace math {
    double getFirst(Comp a) {
        return a.first;
    }
    ...
}
```

`Comp` file: every function return `Comp` or `double`. I call function from `cal.cpp` file several times

cal.h

```cpp
#include "comp.h"
#include "helper.h"
namespace math {
    Comp calc(const string& str);
    ...
}
```

cal.cpp

```cpp
#include "eval.h"
namespace math {
    Comp calc(const string& str) {
        ...
    }
}
```

`Cal` file: Some functions return with `comp` type, not just the `cal` function.

helper.h

```cpp
namespace math {
    ...
}
```

helper.cpp

```cpp
#include "helper.h"
namespace math {
    ...
}
```

`helper` file just contains few function that I calling from `cal.cpp` file. Each function is calling several times.

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "calc.h"
int main() {
    string str = "  ";
    pair<double,double> res = math::calc(str);
    cout << res.first << " " << res.second << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In the whole project, I do not use any classes.

I included every file that I calling except the c++ original file.

I use the std namespace in each file but I do not write it here.

I absolutely no idea what could be the problem with my code.

If I also include `cal.cpp` in the `main.cpp` the code editor says `undefined reference` to each file that I calling from `helper.h`. I do not want to include `cal.cpp` in the `main` file I just mentioned it

Comment: Are you sure that the error comes from the code editor and not from the compiler? Sometimes the editor misinterprets things in large code bases. For this you have to re-parse the file or just leave it (if the compiler compiles it fine).

Comment: The compiler give me error as well

Comment: When the error occurs? During compilation or while linking modules?

Comment: Also what's the name of the file - you've pointed out _cal.h_ and not _calc.h_

Comment: During the linking modules

Comment: You have to link it properly in order for the definitions being available for all units/final executable

Comment: Other weird thing if I do not use `cal.h` file and I inculde `cal.cpp` file into `main.cpp` file I can run the code and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compile all your project's *.cpp files and then link them (results of compilation) properly - the linking process depends on the environment/IDE you're using, just look it up. If you're not linking it properly the final executable wont have all the functions definitions that requires, hence getting *undefined reference*.

Comment: Other weird thing if I do not use `cal.h` file and I inculde `cal.cpp` file into `main.cpp` file I can run the code and it works fine

Comment: It's not weird, the content of the file (either .h or .cpp) is being "pasted" into the main.cpp. _include_ directive in c++ simply "copies" the content of the file that is being included. Therefore in this case all the content of _cal.cpp_ file is being included in _main.cpp_ and therefore all the functions definitions are available - hence no "undefined reference"

Comment: Once again, first compile all the cpp files so that you have the binary equivalents of those files, afterwards link them together in order to get the final executable result

Comment: It is working now, I just have to rebuilt the project, I said a weird stuff, that I do not known that can occure. Luckily it is working and I learnt somthing that I do not know before